# Percent of total cells that have positive values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fractions

I am looking to calculate the percent of years a company has had positive earnings. My dataframe has thousands of companies, and so I am trying to figure out how to isolate each company to perform this calculation.

[image: Sample Data]

Using the sample data of one company above and assuming RSG.AX was founded in 2007, I want the resulting column to read:

```
             percentPositiveEarnings
(NaN/12) =   NaN
(5/11)   =   0.45
(4/10)   =   0.4
(3/9)    =   0.33
(3/8)    =   0.375
(3/7)    =   0.429
(3/6)    =   0.5
(2/5)    =   0.4
(1/4)    =   0.25
(1/3)    =   0.33
(1/2)    =   0.5
(1/1)    =   1
```

Each cell in this column should calculate the number of years the company has had positive earnings divided by the total number of years since it was founded.

I am not sure if I have to use `.groupby()` to separate each company's data, as I have never used it before. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please do not include your data as picture. Copy/Paste them in the question as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RIC': ['RSG.AX'] * 12 + ['IBM'] * 2, 
    'Date': list(range(2007, 2019)) + list(range(2000, 2002)), 
    'FCF': [4.66, -2.36, -9.3, -5.7, 7.7, 1.2, -2.6, -2.4, -4.3, 1.1, 4.22, np.nan, 1, -2]
})
```

Note that I chose to ignore `NaN` valuess rather than have the result become `NaN`.

```
df = df.sort_values(['RIC', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
pct_profitable = df.groupby('RIC')['FCF'].transform(
    lambda s: s.gt(0).cumsum() / s.notnull().cumsum())
>>> df.assign(pct_profitable=pct_profitable)
       RIC  Date   FCF  pct_profitable
0      IBM  2000  1.00        1.000000
1      IBM  2001 -2.00        0.500000
2   RSG.AX  2007  4.66        1.000000
3   RSG.AX  2008 -2.36        0.500000
4   RSG.AX  2009 -9.30        0.333333
5   RSG.AX  2010 -5.70        0.250000
6   RSG.AX  2011  7.70        0.400000
7   RSG.AX  2012  1.20        0.500000
8   RSG.AX  2013 -2.60        0.428571
9   RSG.AX  2014 -2.40        0.375000
10  RSG.AX  2015 -4.30        0.333333
11  RSG.AX  2016  1.10        0.400000
12  RSG.AX  2017  4.22        0.454545
13  RSG.AX  2018   NaN        0.454545
```